2010 Jaguar XF Occasional crank, but no start
2010 XF 4.3 V8 Occasionally, will not start when the engine is hot. This happens once a month or so. It's very irregular.
This usually happens when it is driven for 15 to 30 minutes, ( so fully warmed up) then parked, to go into a store or something similar. Then when I come out and try to start the car the engine cranks but does not start.  This does not happen all the time, but on occasion.  If the car is allowed to sit longer, it then starts and drives fine.
There is no issues while driving. It idles fine, drives smooth and with plenty of power.
There are no OBD codes stored.
This problem is very unpredictable, because it can and has happened at random times. My wife and I are hesitant to drive it because you never know if it will leave you sitting waiting for the engine to cool to get it started. (The engine does not need to be completely cooled down. More a time thing.)
An example: Drive to the grocery store and do weekly shopping, (spend 1/2 hour in the store)  Come out and the car starts.
Stop at the grocery store on the way home from work, ( spend 10 minutes in the store) Come out and the car will crank but not start, but this is only on occasion!
This is driving us crazy.  Any insight is appreciated.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
